# Pagination for custom query won't let me back on page 1

Tags: posts, wp-query, pagination

I have a custom query …

```
<?php
/**
 * The loop that displays the posts.
 */
?>

<ul class="post-items">
<?php

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => array('post', 'wr_raffle'),
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'paged' => (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1,
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
```

At the bottom of this document I have this …

```
?>      
</ul>

<div class="pagination wrapper clear">
    <?php
        $endsize = $midsize = 1;
        $type = 'plain';
        $loop->query_vars['paged'] > 1 ? $current = $loop->query_vars['paged'] : $current = 1;

        // Sanitize input argument values
        if ( ! in_array( $type, array( 'plain', 'list', 'array' ) ) ) $type = 'plain';
        $endsize = (int) $endsize;
        $midsize = (int) $midsize;

        // Setup argument array for paginate_links()
        $pagination = array(
            //'base'          => @add_query_arg('paged','%#%'),
            'format'       => '?page=%#%#blog',
            'total'         => $loop->max_num_pages,
            'current'       => $current,
            'show_all'      => false,
            'end_size'      => $endsize,
            'mid_size'      => $midsize,
            'type'          => $type,
            'prev_next'     => false,
            //'paged'         => $loop->query_vars['paged']
        );

        echo paginate_links( $pagination );
    ?>
</div>
```

Well, I've already read quite a few threads about this but can't figure out why my pagination "almost" works.

My pagination works on every page, just if I navigate back to page 1 the pagination link doesn't work.

– Before I clicked on Page Number Two: http://cl.ly/TNHx

– After I clicked on Page Number Two: http://cl.ly/TN3o (so there is obviously no href for page-number 1)

Any ideas why my page number 1 link wouldn't work?

Kind regards,
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`paginate_links` doesn't work correctly in some (many) cases if you use the default `base`. If you look at the generated source you can see what is happening: if you are on any page but the first, when using the default base-- `%_%`-- `paginate_links` will print an empty `href=''` for the link back to page one. Of course, browsers will interpret this to be "this page" so the link to page one doesn't work. I consider this very much a bug.

To get around it, pass a `base` argument like: `'base' => site_url('%_%'),`, or `'base' => get_permalink().'%_%',`. Context matters which you choose, so be careful.